# React Router v6 - nested routing without Outlet

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6,
Is it possible to use nested routes without using the Outlet component?

For example:
I have a users page and onClick on a user component it should navigate to the specific user page,

Current try:

```
 <Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
     <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage/>} />
 </Routes>
```

And on click on a specific user:

```
const gotoUserPage = () => {
  navigate('1')
}
```

The gotoUserPage change the URL from '/users' to '/users/1'
but the userPage component doesn't render.

Answer (score 16):

> Is it possible to use nested routes without using the Outlet
> component?

No, *an* `Outlet` component is required in order to render the nested `Route` components.

Either the `Users` component must render an `Outlet` component, or you can render directly an `Outlet` as a layout component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/users" element={<Outlet />}>
    <Route index element={<Users />} />        // "/users"
    <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage/>} /> // "/users/:id"
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Though, a better or more accurate question may be, do you even need to explicitly render an `Outlet` as a layout element? The answer may surpisingly be "no". `Route` components render an `Outlet` by default on the `element` prop.

> The default `<Route element>` is an `<Outlet>`. This means the route
> will still render its children even without an explicit element prop,
> so you can nest route paths without nesting UI around the child route
> elements.

You can simply wrap some nested routes in a `Route` and specify only the `path` for nesting, and the nested routes will be rendered into an `Outlet` by default.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/users">
    <Route index element={<Users />} />        // "/users"
    <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage/>} /> // "/users/:id"
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: I was struggling to understand how I can let a child route "relpace" its parent. The wrapping solution worked like charm, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with using the `<Outlet/>` component? It tells React Router where to render the `<UserPage/>` so without it, there is no place for the page to render, as expected.

If you are wondering how to render the page without it being a child of the `<Users/>` page, then you can try the following:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="users" element={<Outlet />} />
     <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />
     <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage />} />
 </Routes>
```

There are definitely times when a whole different component is necessary, but in most cases, components share certain components, such as nav bar and containers. If you have a nav bar in both the Users and UserPage components, then you may want to consider refactoring it out of both, and put it in a parent component with the nav bar and Outlet. This will help with managing conponents as you scale.

Comment: <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />

throws Error, as nested routes cannot be an absolute path. (start with /)

Any Alternative?

Comment: @AdarshChakraborty Use index route instead `<Route index element={<Users />} />`. https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#index-routes

Comment: The above work if you omit the path attribute: `<Route element={<Users />} />`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use routes without using the `<Outlet />` component, what you simply need to do is shown below. Use the same path of the parent component and add the `:id`:

```
 <Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
   <Route path="users/:id" element={<UserPage/>} />
 </Routes>
```

However if you are concerned about the fact that the `<Outlet />` component renders on the same page with the Parent component when nested, then you can hide the Parent component when the child component is active like this:

**1. Use Flat Routes**

Add the `<UserPage />` component in the routes like this:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="users" element={<Users />} >
     <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage />} />
   </Route>
 </Routes>
```

**2. Parent Component Conditional Render**

Add a condition to NOT render contents of Parent component if there exist a `params.id` property, this uses Outlet but helps you avoid showing some elements.

```
let params = useParams();
<div>
!params.id && (<div>
*render your contents here* </div>)
<Outlet />
</div>
```

So whenever the child component is loaded, the Parent component is not visible.

Comment: Just a correction in terminology, your first example isn't route nesting, just a flat list of routes. In the second example, the `Users` component would ***necessarily*** need to render an `Outlet` component for the nested route to render `UserPage`, which is the exact problem OP was asking about or trying to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

This is an optimised way of doing what @hellocng has explained:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="users" element={<Outlet />}>
     <Route index element={<Users />} />
     <Route path=":id" element={<UserPage />} />
   </Route>
 </Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using nested `<Routes></Routes>` component in react-router-dom v6 and it is working. But in console sometimes there is warning message `"No routes matched location ...someLocation..."` and i guess if this method is correct. But it is not convenient for me to use `<Outlet/>`.
In the example below `PageRouting` contains `Page`. `Page` contains `NestedPageRouting`. And `NestedPageRouting` contains `NestedPage`. Slash and asterisk (`/*`) in the end of path segment allow nested routing. First slash in the path in comments assumes that `<PageRouting/>` is the root routing.

```
function PageRouting(){
  return <Routes>
    {/* path: /page */}
    <Route path="page/*" element={<Page/>}/>
    <Route path='*' element={<div>No routes matched</div>}/>
  </Routes>
}

function Page(){
  return <div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <NestedPageRouting/>
  </div>
}

function NestedPageRouting(){
  return <Routes>
    {/* path: /page/nestedPage */}
    <Route path="nestedPage/*" element={<NestedPage/>}/>
    <Route path='*' element={<div>No routes matched</div>}/>
  </Routes>
}

function NestedPage(){
  return <div>Some Nested Content</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with some trick.
Here is my trick

- first crate a outlet component ( `<OutletPage />` )
- then create page which actually needs to render when somebody visit that route

Like this

```
<Route path="profile" element={<ProfilePageOutlet />}>
     <Route index element={<ProfilePage />} />
     <Route path="my-profile" element={<MyProfilePage />} />
</Route>
```

`<ProfilePageOutlet />` looks like this

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function ProfilePageOutlet() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

export default ProfilePageOutlet;
```

`<MyProfilePage />` is a simple page

Comment: They specifically said "without using the Outlet component", this clearly does not answer the question